# Django UpdateView: How to display the original values?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm using Django UpdateView to update a Model class

```
class TestCase(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   executable = models.CharField(max_length=1023) 
   parameter_value_list = models.TextField()   
   test_type = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
   created_by = models.CharField(max_length=200, default = "user")     
   create_datetime = models.DateTimeField("testcase created on", auto_now = True)
```

My view is as:

```
class MyEditCaseView(UpdateView):
       model = TestCase
       fields = ['name', 'executable', 'parameter_value_list', 'test_type']
       template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
       def get_success_url(self):
           return reverse("myApp:testCase")
```

My template is as:

```
<form action="{% url 'myApp:editCase' case.id %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="submit" value="Edit">    
    </form>
```

urls:

```
path('editCase/<int:pk>/', views.MyEditCaseView.as_view(), name='editCase')
```

It works OK, but I have 3 questions:

1. The update view page pop out is blank for all fields even they have old values. I won't like to change all fields. How to show the old values, if I don't want update all fields?
2. The default lay out of the update view page seems not elegant. Can I change the style?
3. When clicking the input box, saying Name field, a drop down list will show to give some historic values I had used as candidates. Can I delete or change this historic list?

[image: The Update Page I got]

Comment: Why don't you render your `{{ form }}`?

Comment: What view/path is rendering this template? It doesn't match the output from the resulting page

Comment: @Willem After reading Donghyun's answer, I understand your meaning now. I didn't render {{form}} because I didn't realise the update_form template is the place defining the updating page. I copied from the tutorial and forget it. I know now. Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: @lain Sorry I didn't understand your question yet.

Answer (score 1):

Django form can be spread out.

```
    <!--begin::Form-->
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in form.fields %}
                <input name="{{ field.name }}" type="text" value="{{ field.value }}"/>
            {% endfor %}
    </form>
    <!--end::Form-->
```

1. The update view page pop out is blank for all fields even they have old values. I won't like to change all fields. How to show the old values, if I don't want update all fields?

You can use default value as above example, value field.

2. The default lay out of the update view page seems not elegant. Can I change the style?

You can use class attribute in each input fields.

3. When clicking the input box, saying Name field, a drop down list will show to give some historic values I had used as candidates. Can I delete or change this historic list?

If you set autucomplete attribute as off, then any history would not appear.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks.